# How to get specific data from json object in array (Local Storage) - Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7, cart, shopping-cart

In my angular project have shopping cart feature. Every product i will store in local storage as a object in array.

#### 1. So i want to get each product price (productPrice) from json object, to show total price in cart.

#### 2. Anther thing is i want to delete specific object from local storage, array of cart item by project ID.

can any help me to do that.

### Cart.component.ts

```
public cartItems :any; 

ngOnInit() {
  if(this.cartService.getFromLocalStrorage()){
    this.cartItems = this.cartService.getFromLocalStrorage(); 
    console.log(this.cartItems); //result show in below  
  }
}
```

### Cart-services.service.ts

```
public getFromLocalStrorage() {
  const  cart =  JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartObject'));
  return cart;
}
```

### Result - Console Log

```
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

0:
productId: 2
productName: "product 2"
productPrice: 1000
productQuantity: 9
productSelectedTypeId: 1
productSelectedTypeName: "100 ml"

////---------------------------
```

#### In local storage

```
 [{productId: 2, productSelectedTypeId: 1, productSelectedTypeName: "100 ml", productQuantity: 9,…},…]

0: {productId: 2, productSelectedTypeId: 1, productSelectedTypeName: "100 ml", productQuantity: 9,…}
1: {productId: 2, productSelectedTypeId: 3, productSelectedTypeName: "300 ml", productQuantity: 1,…}
2: {productId: 2, productSelectedTypeId: 2, productSelectedTypeName: "200 ml", productQuantity: 1,…}
3: {productId: 3, productSelectedTypeId: null, productSelectedTypeName: null, productQuantity: 24,…}
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with angular, its just javascript use `map` as the answer below suggest to get the price and use `filter` to remove an specific object from the array and then update the localstorage with the filtered array... btw. I wouldn't use localstorage since it might not work as expected due to different implementations in various browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple `.map()` to extract an array only containing the prices, and a `reduce()` to add up the total. Example below.

---

**Solution**

```
public ngOnInit(): void
{
  if(this.cartService.getFromLocalStrorage())
  {
    this.cartItems = this.cartService.getFromLocalStrorage(); 
    console.log(this.cartItems); //result show in below  

    const prices = this.cartItems.map(data => data.productPrice); 
    console.log(prices); // array of all the prices

    const total = prices.reduce((a, b) => a + b));
    console.log(total); // total prices from array of prices
  }
}
```

To update the value in the local store you can filter the array and re-save it.

```
this.cartItems = this.cartItems.filter(data => data.productId !== 3);
localStorage.setItem('cartObject', JSON.stringify(this.cartItems));
```

---

**Documentation**

[.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) // [.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) // [setting item by key in local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) // [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

---

**Edit**

For the multiplication including quantity of each product add it into the map

```
const prices = this.cartItems.map( data => (data.productPrice * data.productQuantity) ); 
console.log(prices); // array of all the prices
```

Then once again use the `reduce()` function on this for the total prices of all including quantity.

Comment: In `const total = prices.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; }, 0);
    console.log(total); // total prices from array of prices` Can you tell me How to multiply with `productQuantity`

Comment: the removal is not correct, he wants to remove an entry in the json-array therefore the original must be filtered and the filtered array must be applied to the `cartObject` entry in the localstorage

Comment: i added local storage array to question, as a example, i want to delete ProductId-->3 item object from that array. you got my idea.

Comment: I think the example I gave should work please check and let me know, also added quantity * price in

Comment: yeah friend. total price works nice. but specific cart object delete function was not clear.

Comment: I want to delete that object from array, i did not want to update it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192801/discussion-between-thevin-malaka-and-dince12).

Answer (score 1):

I think you would like to do something like this

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export interface ICartItem {
    productId: number;
    productName: string;
    productPrice: number;
    productQuantity: number;
    productSelectedTypeId: number;
    productSelectedTypeName: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class CartService {

    public cart: ICartItem[] = [];

    constructor() {
        this.load();
    }

    load() {
        if ( localStorage.getItem('cartObject') !== null ) {
            this.cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartObject'));
        }
    }

    save() {
        localStorage.setItem('cartObject', JSON.stringify(this.cart));
    }

    add(cartItem: ICartItem) {
        this.cart.push(cartItem);
        this.save();
    }

    deleteById(id: number) {
        const items = this.cart.filter(
            cartItem => cartItem.productId === id);

        if ( items.length === 1 ) {
            const index = this.cart.indexOf(items[ 0 ]);
            this.cart.splice(index, 1);
            this.save();
        }
    }

    deleteCartItem(cartItem: ICartItem) {
        const itemIndex = this.cart.indexOf(cartItem);

        if ( itemIndex > -1 ) {
            this.cart.splice(itemIndex, 1);
            this.save();
        }
    }

    deleteByIndex(index: number) {
        this.cart.splice(index, 1);
        this.save();
    }

    calculateTotalPrice(): number {
        return this.cart
            .reduce((
                currentValue,
                cartItem
            ) => (cartItem.productPrice * cartItem.productQuantity) + currentValue, 0);
    }
}
```

So essentially what I did was save it once we change it. And load it once we load the application. So that you do not have to worry about keeping the localStorage up to date with the array. As long as you use the functions you should be fine.

I've also gone ahead and created some delete examples.

Hope this helps you out!